# SwiftUI TextField changing color in dark mode

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, textfield

I have some strange behavior using SwiftUI and a TextField.

In the light mode of macOS my TextField is looking the same colorwise if it is focused with the cursor or not (this is the behavior I want). However, if I activate dark mode in the system settings I get a strange highlighting effect in the background whenever I focus the TextField with the cursor.

I attached some screenshots of the issue here:

Light mode, normal:

[image]

Dark mode, unfocused, normal:

[image]

Dark mode, focused, weird highlighting:

[image]

This is the code for my search view:

```
struct SearchView: View {
    @Binding var searchText: String
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            TextField("Search", text: $searchText).modifier(TextFieldClearButton(text: $searchText)).textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle()).padding(.vertical, 8).padding(.horizontal, 5)
            
        }
        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).stroke(Color(NSColor.separatorColor), lineWidth: 1))
    }
}
```

and the ViewModifier:

```
struct TextFieldClearButton: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var text: String
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        HStack {
            content
            
            if !text.isEmpty {
                Button(
                    action: { self.text = "" },
                    label: {
                        Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.secondary)
                    }
                ).buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why this happens or how I can prevent this?

Comment: issue on your modifier check or send modifier code.

Comment: I agree, pasting your View Modifier code would be helpful.

This article on handling dark mode may also be useful to you. https://jacobzivandesign.com/technology/dark_mode_swift_ui/

Comment: I added the ViewModifier code to the description, however I experience the same issue if I remove it from the TextField. Any ideas?

Comment: @ikbal any ideas?

Comment: @Jake any ideas?

Comment: Copying and pasting your code into Xcode Beta 4 I don't get that visual defect. I imagine you have some modifier on one of the presenting views that cascades to this search view

Comment: @Jake Thank you! I found the root cause, it is because I placed it inside of a List. Now I just need to find out if I can disable the effect or if I need to move it out of the list and recreate the padding it automatically got inside the list

Comment: Awesome work! let me know what you find.

Comment: In the end I had to move it out of the list to disable the weird behavior and recreate the styling (padding)